# Add an Item each sublist to the list of Lists in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am very new programming in Python, please bear with me.

I have a List of Lists like below :

```
[['Name', 'Status', 'AppSpace', 'MgmtPort', 'Agent'], 
['Test-Node4', 'Running', 'Test', '2231', 'machine1'],
['Test-Node1', 'Running', 'Test', '2231', 'Machine2'], 
['Test-Node3', 'Running', 'Test', '2231', 'machine3'], 
['Test-Node2', 'Running', 'Test', '2231', 'Machine4'], 
['Test-Node5', 'Running', 'Test', '2231', 'machine5']]
```

And I wish to add few Items (at the beginning) to each of the sub-list. so It should be looking like below :

```
[['DOMAIN', 'Application' , 'Name', 'Status', 'AppSpace', 'MgmtPort', 'Agent'], 
['UAT' , 'CaseCreation' , 'Test-Node4', 'Running', 'Test', '2231', 'machine1'],
['UAT' , 'CaseCreation' , 'Test-Node1', 'Running', 'Test', '2231', 'Machine2'], 
['UAT' , 'CaseCreation' , 'Test-Node3', 'Running', 'Test', '2231', 'machine3'], 
['UAT' , 'CaseCreation' , 'Test-Node2', 'Running', 'Test', '2231', 'Machine4'], 
['UAT' , 'CaseCreation' , 'Test-Node5', 'Running', 'Test', '2231', 'machine5']]
```

I would have tried reading SubList over a for loop and manipulate data into a CSV something, but is there a better way?

Please Suggest.

Answer (score 2):

i think that the answers above would give you what you want. But, have you tried pandas library ? I think it would be a nice way to manage that kind of data. Look this example:

```
import pandas as pd

original_list = [['Name', 'Status', 'AppSpace', 'MgmtPort', 'Agent'],
['Test-Node4', 'Running', 'Test', '2231', 'machine1'],
['Test-Node1', 'Running', 'Test', '2231', 'Machine2'],
['Test-Node3', 'Running', 'Test', '2231', 'machine3'],
['Test-Node2', 'Running', 'Test', '2231', 'Machine4'],
['Test-Node5', 'Running', 'Test', '2231', 'machine5']]

df_original= pd.DataFrame(original_list[1:], columns = original_list[0])  #Convert the list into a DataFrame

new_item = ["UAT","UAT","UAT","UAT","UAT"]  #Create a list with the data, or a series
new_item2 = ["CaseCreation","CaseCreation","CaseCreation","CaseCreation","CaseCreation"]

df_original.insert(0,"DOMAIN",new_item)  # Then you use insert to add the item wherever you want.
df_original.insert(1,"Application",new_item2)

print(df_original)
```

Output:

```
 DOMAIN   Application        Name   Status AppSpace MgmtPort     Agent
0    UAT  CaseCreation  Test-Node4  Running     Test     2231  machine1
1    UAT  CaseCreation  Test-Node1  Running     Test     2231  Machine2
2    UAT  CaseCreation  Test-Node3  Running     Test     2231  machine3
3    UAT  CaseCreation  Test-Node2  Running     Test     2231  Machine4
4    UAT  CaseCreation  Test-Node5  Running     Test     2231  machine5
```

With pandas you can manipulate each column and row as you want, even convert con CSV,EXCl in a easy way.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert items in the beginning of each sublist like below:

```
ar = [['Name', 'Status', 'AppSpace', 'MgmtPort', 'Agent'], 
['Test-Node4', 'Running', 'Test', '2231', 'machine1'],
['Test-Node1', 'Running', 'Test', '2231', 'Machine2'], 
['Test-Node3', 'Running', 'Test', '2231', 'machine3'], 
['Test-Node2', 'Running', 'Test', '2231', 'Machine4'], 
['Test-Node5', 'Running', 'Test', '2231', 'machine5']]

first_row = ['DOMAIN', 'Application']
other_row = ['UAT' , 'CaseCreation']
for i in range(len(ar)):
    if i==0:
        for elem in first_row[::-1]:
            ar[i].insert(0,elem)
    else:
        for elem in other_row[::-1]:
            ar[i].insert(0,elem)   
print(ar)
```

Output:

```
[['DOMAIN', 'Application', 'Name', 'Status', 'AppSpace', 'MgmtPort', 'Agent'], ['UAT', 'CaseCreation', 'Test-Node4', 'Running', 'Test', '2231', 'machine1'], ['UAT', 'CaseCreation', 'Test-Node1', 'Running', 'Test', '2231', 'Machine2'], ['UAT', 'CaseCreation', 'Test-Node3', 'Running', 'Test', '2231', 'machine3'], ['UAT', 'CaseCreation', 'Test-Node2', 'Running', 'Test', '2231', 'Machine4'], ['UAT', 'CaseCreation', 'Test-Node5', 'Running', 'Test', '2231', 'machine5']]
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want you can use `insert` method which allow to insert at any position in list:

```
list_a=[['Name', 'Status', 'AppSpace', 'MgmtPort', 'Agent'],
['Test-Node4', 'Running', 'Test', '2231', 'machine1'],
['Test-Node1', 'Running', 'Test', '2231', 'Machine2'],
['Test-Node3', 'Running', 'Test', '2231', 'machine3'],
['Test-Node2', 'Running', 'Test', '2231', 'Machine4'],
['Test-Node5', 'Running', 'Test', '2231', 'machine5']]


a=['DOMAIN','Application']
b=['UAT' ,'CaseCreation']



for first,second in enumerate(list_a):
    if first==0:
        for item_1 in a:
                second.insert(0, item_1)


    else:
        for item in b:
            second.insert(0,item)
print(list_a)
```

Answer (score 0):

The iterative approach is what's needed, but if you wanted your code to be more concise, you can use the map() function from python, which allows you to perform element-wise operations to your list.

```
new = list(map( lambda x: ['Name', 'Status'] + x if(x[0] is  'Name') else ['UAT' , 'CaseCreation'] + x, oldlist ) )
```